# Are functions that are equal to a constant as you take a limit to infinty O(1)?

Tags: asymptotics

The below function converges to a constant as you take n to infinity.

$f(n)=(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$

$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n = e$

Would this imply that it is O(1) since you can just upper bound it with a constant?

Comment: You say "the function below" but don't define a function.

Comment: For the definition of O, can you find a suitable constant factor? Is this possible in general?

Comment: In general, if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ exists and is a constant, then $f(n) = O(g(n))$. What you are asking is the special case where $g(n) = 1$.

Comment: Try to apply the definition of $\mathcal O$ notation. Is there a particular place where you run into questions or problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition of $O$ notation, if you can find a constant $c$ and $n_0$ such that $f(n) < c g(n)$ for all $n > n_0$, we can say $f(n) = O(g(n))$. In this case, suppose $n_0 = 1000$ and $c = 3$ and $g(n) = 1$. You can show that as $f(n)$ is increasing function and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n) = e$, it is true $f(n) < 3 g(n)$ for all $n > 1000$. Therefore, $f(n) = O(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Bounded functions are O(1). Functions that are bounded from some point on are O(1), and they are exactly the functions that are O(1). Any function with a limit is bounded from some point onward, but many other functions are as well and therefore O(1).